# Programmatically disable notification for Screenclip/Snipping Tool

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, snipping, snipping-tool

My application is using `ms-screenclip:` URI scheme to launch Windows 10/11 built in screenshotting tool.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-screen-snipping

My question is, is there an undocumented way of disabling the notification for the snipping tool that pops up after a screenshot is taken for this specific instance so user settings aren't affected? I'd like to do so programmatically without user involvement. It breaks the flow of my application.

There is a way to disable it via registry programmatically, however it requires for my app to have elevated Administrative privileges to do so.

[Example of notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW8Sz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the registry

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App] "Enabled"=dword:00000000`

Perhaps before and after snipping.

Comment: Editing the Registry *once* during program *installation*, with *acceptance by the user to allow* this Registry change, is not a bad idea. However, since it requires UAC to *make* a Registry change, that would involve twice the number of notifications! ;-)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Not if running the program already requires administrative privileges, right?

Comment: most programs performing minor tasks do *not* run as Administrator, and I'd distrust an application that *always* requires that privilege for a minor task. Note the standard practice for most applications that perform their own updates: a UAC dialog is shown to allow system changes.

Comment: OP hasn't told us about their application so we don't know if it does a minor or major task. We also don't know if it already requires admin privileges.

Comment: I think this gets me what I need. Thanks